# Remote Desktop Connection abrupt behavior.

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

When I do "Remote Desktop Connection" to my Windows system , my system gets locked automatically but from now past few days when I logged into my windows system remotely it doesn't get locked and moreover i can access my system from different machine simultaneously and it doesn't get locked.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to get back to the old way of working, or find out why it has changed?

Comment: The consumer versions of Windows 7 do not allow simultaneously  remote connections.  So something else is going on.

Comment: @TimRadcliffe I want to switch to old way and I want to know the reason why it occurred.

Comment: @Ramhound Exactly!! but i am curious about from where and how i can check the changes done in system.

Comment: @Devraj  - What I am saying.  What you describe is not possible with Windows 7 Professional unless your not using the default built-in remote desktop application.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm sorry I forget to mention. I am using Windows 7 Professional built-in remote desktop application. Is their any way to check any logs or something where i can find the root cause of this.

Comment: @Ramhound it is actually possible, just a few reg key edits to make it think it is the Server version of RDP...

Comment: @AthomSfere - If the author indicates he has performed these modifications the question has merit, otherwise, there is something else going on which requires more information.

Comment: @Devraj - Well as I indicated.  Its literally not possible to make multiple remote connections using the built-in tool to the same Windows 7 installation.  Only Windows Server products allow for that provided you have the seats.  There are unofficial registry hacks, but you don't indicate you did those, which would be relevant information.

Comment: @Ramhound I am just pointing out that *not possible* is not true. Who knows what hacks this user or another user might have inadvertently ran.

Comment: @AthomSfere
and Ramhound : Hey!! Sorry for replying late I was out. "Win7LogonBackgroundChanger" this software i downloaded and used to change the background Image. Is their any problem with this. Please suggest way to investigate this.

Comment: Hi guys, there is nothing I am able to find, So I restored my computer and its working as expected.